# Run This Script On Every Tab Except "Main" Tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script working well, but I'm uncertain how to make it run on every tab not labeled "Main".  Thanks in advance!

```
function hideRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Dude");       // Enter sheet name

var row = s.getRange('A2:A').getValues();  // Enter column letter that has the text "hide" and  "unhide"
var cell = s.getRange('A1').getValue();

s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
for(var i=0; i < row.length; i++){ if(row[i] != cell) { s.hideRows(i+2, 1); }   // Value to hide
     
}
}
```

Jerome

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi, was your original question solved by [Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70888683)? From my perspective, it's not clear how you want to trigger this. User edit? Via button, or custom menu or manually from the script? Or when the spreadsheet opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Run on every sheet except Main

I assume that you are running the onEdit trigger.

```
function hideRows(e) {
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  if(s.getName() == "Main") return;
  var row = s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow() -1 ).getValues().flat();
  var cell = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
  s.showRows(1, s.getLastRow());
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i] != cell) { s.hideRows(i + 2, 1); }
  }
}
```

Want to exclude more sheets

```
function hideRows(e) {
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  const ex = ['Main','Sheetx'];//excluded sheet names
  const idx = ex.indexOf(s.getName());
  if(~idx) return;
  var row = s.getRange(2,1,s.getLastRow() -1 ).getValues().flat();
  var cell = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
  s.showRows(1, s.getLastRow());
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i] != cell) { s.hideRows(i + 2, 1); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper.  If I wanted to exclude any other sheets I would do the following?

`if(s.getName() == "Main" || "Other") return;`

Comment: It's giving me an error, 'TypeError: Cannot read property range of undefined'.  I'm guessing its referring to the range reference in the const?

Comment: with reference to the first comment that's not the question you asked.

Comment: with reference to the second comment you cannot run the code from the script editor because I am using the onedit event object.

Comment: Okay, gotcha with the onEdit event.  However, if I edit the sheet, it doesn't run.

Comment: You can use `e.source.toast('flag name')`  and Logger.log() to debug the code.

Comment: Have you created the installable trigger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241481/discussion-between-jump-ace-and-cooper).